# Poisson Process: probability

Tags: probability

Find the chance that the fifth waiting time of the length at least T for an arrival, occurs at the time of tenth arrival.
{N(t), t>0} with rate lampda

Comment: I don't know what that means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that the waiting time between two arrivals is $\ge T$ is $e^{-\lambda T}$. Call this number $p$.

We want the probability that there is a wait of $\ge T$ between the $9$-th and $10$-th arrival, and that this kind of wait has occurred exactly $4$ times in the $9$ arrivals before that.

Call a wait of $\ge T$ a success (it gives workers a much needed break). We want the probability of exactly $4$ successes in $9$ trials, followed by success.

The required probability is therefore 
$$\binom{9}{4}p^4(1-p)^5p.$$